# PyGTK changing theme for popup menu

Tags: python, programming, pygtk

I spent few hours searching on google and I gave up now...

I need to change background for popup menu in my app.
It set to whatever system default theme is... and I need this to be set to Radiance for all the time.

any ideas how to achieve this?

[image: Here is how it looks now and this need to be light color]

Comment: I don't think that property is properly exposed in any pygtk methods.  So using normal methods, you can't

Comment: I can change toolbar style so why should be a problem changing menu style ?

Comment: There's not a method for it: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkmenu.html

Comment: So do you think there any kind of workaround for it ?

Comment: No.  If there's a workaround it's not a solution it's a band-aid.

Comment: I just found this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197761/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-gtk-menuitem

Comment: Congrats, you just proved your question to be off-topic, already answered, and a duplicate all at once.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing, you may want to flag it as one or the other, then.  Off topic, though?  Honestly, how is this off-topic?

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing thanks for your "Help" it looks like someone was right telling me that askubuntu is not good place for asking questions about programming and you simply prove it.

Comment: @Majster-pl: I think AskUbuntu is a perfectly reasonable place to ask a programming question like this, especially as Canonical is trying very hard to encourage a new developer community. Please hang in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I theme my popup windows like so:

```
#Use Css themes
css = Gtk.CssProvider()
css.load_from_data("""
        .popup {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); border: 0px rgba(255,255,255,0);  border-radius: 14px; border-width: 0;  }
    """ 
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), css,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

#Get popup parent and set rgba visual so I can do transparency
pwindow=self.popup.get_parent()
screen=pwindow.get_screen()
pwindow.set_visual(screen.get_rgba_visual())

#Give popups the popup CSS class
self.popup.get_style_context().add_class('popup')
```

I also use cairo to draw the popup window and give it a nice texture. To do that I just connect its 'draw' signal to a call back.

I would look at the Radiance Gtk theme to find out what the background color is and use that for the background-color css setting. You can find it in `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/Gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. If you don't need transparency, then skip the pwindow stuff above and just add the style_context to your popup.

Comment: This is what I was looking for ;-)
Thank you so much @Ian B.  I will only need to tweak it a little bit for my purpose

Comment: @Ian - Isn't that pygi not pygtk?

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing, Yes- but I have found that many people (especially beginners) are using the term pygtk interchangeably. If he is developing an app using quickly, more than likely he's really using pygi. If not, he should migrate anyway